# How to do a prefix query in Apache Lucy with Perl?

Tags: perl, apache-lucy

I am using [Apache Lucy](http://lucy.apache.org/) to speed up a typeahead (autocomplete) field on a Web form. I am querying against nearly 800k records. I have a working setup but would like to limit my responses to terms that begin with the query string.  Currently the query matchers either match the whole word or if I tokenize with `/./` I can match the query against partials of whole words.

While going through the documentation I found [Lucy::Docs::Cookbook::CustomQueryParser](http://p3rl.org/Lucy%3a%3aDocs%3a%3aCookbook%3a%3aCustomQueryParser).

On that page under the heading [Extending the query language](http://p3rl.org/Lucy%3a%3aDocs%3a%3aCookbook%3a%3aCustomQueryParser#Extending-the-query-language), there was a reference to `PrefixQuery`.  This package does not exist in Lucy and I had to do some more searching.  Eventually I found the [PrefixQuery.pm](https://github.com/apache/lucy/blob/master/perl/sample/PrefixQuery.pm) code sample in lucy's git repository.

Note that this package references another non-existent package called `Lucy::Search::Tally`. Removing the references to tally allowed me to get this example working, but it is far from a functional matcher. It doesn't handle multiple fields, no scoring, etc…

Does anyone know of a way to make Lucy do prefix matching without all this mucking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution in the Apache docs.

http://lucy.apache.org/docs/perl/Lucy/Docs/Cookbook/CustomQuery.html